# A story where everyone is programmed (or bred) to be non-violent and non-confrontational except for one

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember reading a story where everyone is programmed (or bred) to be non-violent and non-confrontational.  Only one man escapes this and he goes on a trail of robbery and intimidation. I can remember very little else except that I'm pretty sure it was a well-known author. Also it was before, say, the 1980s

Can anyone tell me the title?

There was an incident where he threw ice cold water on a woman having said it would be boiling. The intention was to cause her distress without actual damage.

Comment: Is this a short story or a novel?  Can you recall any details of the cover?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235168/outcast-boy-meets-girl-underwater -- for that question, the accepted answer was "The Country of the Kind" by Damon Knight.

Comment: definitely Country of the Kind -- the ice water confirms it.

Comment: @Lorendiac - Yes, this is it. I don't remember the underwater scene and I'm amazed you were able to make the connection. Thanks!